# include CSS on my View XHTML

Tags: css, jsf

I want to include CSS on my View XHTML. 
here's my project tree:

```
WebContent
 |-- pages
 |    |-- template.xhtml
 |-- resources
 |    |-- css
 |       |--style.css
```

i tried with

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
</h:head>
```

but nothing happen when i deploy my web application in my Tomcat Server.

Comment: You can include it like <h:outputStylesheet name="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/style.css" library="css" />

Comment: thank you  for your answer but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this : `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />`

Comment: did you tried to put the <h:outputStyleSheet in the body ?